# Logstash: query parameter lower than a value through elasticsearch plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

With executing searches, I know that if I want to query a pamareter lower than a certain value i have to execute the following script:

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
            "range": {
                "length": {
                     "lte": "22"
                 }
               }
            }
       ]
     }
   }
  }
```

However, i want to do the same thing through the elastic plugin in logstash.

```
    elasticsearch{
         query =>= "...."
    }
```

But I didn't find how to do that. (and the website doesn't give any help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html)

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), you can do it like this

```
elasticsearch{
     query =>= "length:{* to 22]"
}
```

Also note that at some point, we might be able to use the query DSL if [this issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elasticsearch/issues/13) gets some traction.

Comment: I just needed to change 'to' by 'TO' and it worked for me ;) !